# Getting Total Record by Group by in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have one query in SQL, want to convert it to Linq. My Query is :

```
select count(tbs.tbsid) as CNTSeats,tbm.BusNo
from tdp_tourpackageschedule tps
join tdp_tourpackage tp on tp.TourID = tps.FK_TourID
join tdp_tourbusseats tbs on tbs.tbsid = tps.fk_tbsid
join tdp_tourbusmaster tbm on tbm.tbid = tbs.fk_tbid
where fk_tdid = @FKTDID and fk_TourID = @FKTourID and IsOpen = 1
group by tbm.BusNo
```

I tried this Code:

```
var tourAvail = (from ts in entities.tdp_TourPackageSchedule
                 join tp in entities.tdp_TourPackage on ts.FK_TourID equals tp.TourID
                 join tbs in entities.tdp_TourBusSeats on ts.FK_TBSID equals tbs.TBSID
                 join tb in entities.tdp_TourBusMaster on tbs.FK_TBID equals tb.TBID
                 where ts.FK_TDID == TDID && ts.FK_TourID == TourID && ts.IsOpen == 1
                 group tb by tb.BusNo into cnt
                 select new
                 {
                     //BusNo = cnt.bu
                     //Count = cnt.Select(x => x.tdp_TourBusSeats).Distinct().Count()
                 });
```

I don't know how to get count of records, anyone can help ?

Comment: could you try cnt.Count(x => x.SomeId > 0)?

Comment: @J.Steen good explnation of SQL VS LINQ :)

Comment: @J.Steen, My bad, I guess I was too tired. Sorry.

Comment: @gdoron No need to apologise. I was merely disagreeing. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do :

```
var tourAvail = (from ts in entities.tdp_TourPackageSchedule
                 join tp in entities.tdp_TourPackage on ts.FK_TourID equals tp.TourID
                 join tbs in entities.tdp_TourBusSeats on ts.FK_TBSID equals tbs.TBSID
                 join tb in entities.tdp_TourBusMaster on tbs.FK_TBID equals tb.TBID
                 where ts.FK_TDID == TDID && ts.FK_TourID == TourID && ts.IsOpen == 1
                 group tb by tb.BusNo into cnt
                 select new
                 {
                     BusNo = cnt.Key,
                     Count = cnt.Count()
                 }).ToList();
```